# box2d body pass through others bodies

Tags: java, android, mobile, box2d

I got two objects in my game: balls and stars
the balls are static or dynamic bodies.

for the star:
I need to know when a star collide with a ball
**but it needs to pass through the balls and not get affected by the collision**

how am I suppose to do it?
thanks
socksocket

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use [Sensors (6.3)](http://www.box2d.org/manual.html#_Toc258082972).

[Here is a nice tutorial](http://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/sensors) about them.